# change a DataGrid (text) column into combobox ,nd fill it

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

i'm new at visual basic.net ,and i'm trying to build an application which contains a dataGrid View ,one of the columns should be a combobox (i fill it with some information existing in the dataBase using a function ), but still need to know how i can change the state of the columns (from text to combobox) nd how to fill all this combobox , thanks a lot guys

Comment: I have a [blog post](http://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/14/a-basic-example-of-crud-with-datagridview-in-vb-net/) with links to sample projects that demonstrate this.